# Dynamic key names in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I have application which acts as multiple delivery service. All clients must be configured trough application.properties, but I need to have separate all configurations with some id.

Example:

```
app.delivery.method.{clientId}=SFTP
app.{clientId}.sftp.username=some user
app.{clientId}.sftp.password=some pass
etc...
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this, with overriding some spring boot's parser for properties, or using some external library.

I have read almost all of documentation, and saw many examples, but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved a similar problem

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class PropertiesConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    ...

    public String getDeliveryMethod(String clientId) {
        return env.getProperty("app.delivery.method."+clientId);
    }

    public String getClientSftpUsername(String clientId) {
        return env.getProperty("app."+clientId+".sftp.username");
    }
    ...
}
```